# IOS 7 Button Background Does Not Work

Tags: ios, image, button, background

I have a project that comes from IOS6, and now with the button changes of the IOS7 I had to make a background to my project buttons. Although, when I try to set a background image for my buttons it doesn't work! programming or not it doesn't work!

I tryied:

```
[buttonOutlet setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lineStyleScreen.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and the IDE! BOTH DONT WORK!!!

I wonder if it is because I did't updated my storyboard to IOS7.

Comment: It looks like its something with the storyboard, I created another storyboard compatible with IOS7 and its working... I guess I will have to make all the screens again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ios 7 doesnt support regular ios 6 buttons. Do follow this link:

http://dev.iachieved.it/iachievedit/?p=127

Answer (score 1):

Is the button type set to Custom in properties inspector?

Comment: YES it is set to Custom!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the tint color to the button for iOS 7

```
  button.tintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

Note:- set the tint color that will suit to your requirement